# Backreference the entire match in find-and-replace?

Tags: regex, vim

Is there some backreference alias for "entire match"?
I want something like
`:s/foo/\0bar/g`
Where \0 will backreference the entire match, without needing to enclose it as (foo)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You may use `&` or `\0`, see [4.5 Grouping and Backreferences](http://vimregex.com/)

> `&` the whole matched pattern
>   `\0`
>   the whole matched pattern